# How do I save data from multiple services in angular 2 across an entire application?

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns, angular

**Here's what I'm trying to achieve:**
I have an application where I basically want to be able to save data from a number of services (for example, a "logger" service that contains a list of log entries; a "themes" service that contains a list of themes and / or style settings; etc...).  For simplicity's sake, I'm using localStorage to save this data.  As such, I have a generic "LocalStorage" service that defines members for saving and loading key/value pairs as one might expect.

**My question is:**
From a high-level design perspective, how should I approach saving and loading my application data from a single control point (i.e. a "Save / Load" button on a settings page).  Ideally I'd like to be able to implement my application services in such a way that each would implement a common "local storage" interface that would require a "Save Data" and "Load Data" method to be implemented in that service.  The part I'm struggling with is how to iterate across all services that might implement this "local storage" interface and call all of their "save / load" methods at once.  For that matter, I'm not even sure if this is the right approach to take.

I'm still pretty new to Angular 2, so if anyone can shed some light onto this sort of problem, and suggest a sensible solution, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a global service (might even be the `LocalStorageService` but I guess a more UI-specific one would be more appropriate. I use `GlobalUserActions` as an example:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalUserActions {
  // Subject would be better but I don't know TS/RxJS well enough
  // EventEmitter should only be used for @Output()
  saveAll:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter(); 

  doSaveAll() {
    saveAll.emit(null); // or any information that might be useful to components
  }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'any-com',
  ...
}) 
export class AnyComponent {
  constructor(
      private globalUserActions: GlobalUserActions,
      private persistenceService: PersistenceService) {
    this.globalUserActions.saveAll.subscribe(save);
  }

  save(value) {
    this.persistenceService.save(...);
  }
}
```

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ ... ,
    LocalStorageService, 
    // use a generic `PersistenceService` but provide a concrete
    // `LocalStorageService`
    provide(PersistenceService, {useExisting: LocalStorageService})
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  This seems to be along the lines of what I'm trying to achieve.  Could you briefly explain what the PersistenceService is used for in the component constructor?  I'm assuming that this somehow abstracts the service that you want to use to save data (so, in the bootstrapping process, I might choose to set 'useExisting' to 'MyDBService' if I were saving / loading from a DB instead of local storage)

Comment: Yup, that is how I think `PersistenceService` could/should be used.

Comment: Since the OP wanted to iterate across services, shouldn't the call to `subscribe()` and the `save()` method be in services, not components? or am I missing something?

Comment: I read the question again and it seems you are right but it would work the same in services as in components anyway. Subscribe to global events and act on them by invoking functions on global events. I used components because it makes it more obvious what is hub and what is spoke.

Comment: Correct, the subscription would be through bunch of services.  I didn't mention it, as I suspect the general idea would be the same.